# Queryin SQL table with "TEXT" datatype column in java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

i have a "TEXT" type column in a sql database. I queried it with

```
ResultSet rs=db.execSQL(query);
String s=rs.getString("text_field");
```

creates and error. how should i use this text column in my java?

Comment: You're talking about Java, not Javascript, right? You'll also have to say *what* error you're getting.

Comment: no i am using javascript , i want to use the data in this text field in the sql database. i want to know how to use it....

Comment: the string is coming out as null , its not getting the value although the page is compiling

Comment: @Felix: that does not look like JavaScript.

Comment: Your code (`String s=rs.getString("text_field");`) is not valid JavaScript!

Comment: i am sorry , i am new to all this...
i am doing this in a jsp page
with page language java...
does that help?

Comment: i want to query the table in this page and display the data in the text field as output

Comment: You should first see If the query is returning results in the database. Also, please put the error you are getting.

Comment: the query was not returning results in the database... i figured it out now...thanks for all your help guys!!

Comment: 1) [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) != [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), 2) [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) != JavaScript, 3) Writing Java in JSP == [BAD PRACTICE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180202). 4) Do not ignore errors as if they are for decoration. Share them with us. They tell something about the cause of the problem. We can explain you the cause of the problem based on the error. Once you understand the cause of the problem, the solution is nothing more than obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like Java and JDBC (the standard API to uses databases with Java.

Here [is a tutorial, chapter 3.2.2 shows the general solution to your problem](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/JDBCTutorial/). You have to call `next()` on the result set to set the pointer to the next row.

Applied to your code, this should give some progress:

```
ResultSet rs=db.execSQL(query);
while(rs.next()) {
   String s=rs.getString("text_field");
   // do something with s
}
```